# HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found TextBlob and Extra data: line 1 column 352 (char 351) (Phyton)

Tags: pandas

I am doing a data translation to do a sentiment analysis but I have problems when translating with the TextBlob library, as seen in the code, it gives me an HTTP404 error.

FORM 1

```
TextBlob('Odio el código spaguetti').translate(from_lang='es', to='en').sentiment #fr, pt, it
```

I have 2 ways of doing the translation but I would like you to help me understand which is the most optimal because I need to do the code quickly:

in form 2 it gives me an error:JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 352 (char 351)
form 2

```
traductor = google_translator()
texto = df["Comentarios"]
texto_trad = pd.Series([])
for cont in range(len(texto)):
    traduccion = traductor.translate(texto[cont], lang_src='es', lang_tgt='en')
    text_trad[cont] = traduccion
  
print(text_trad)
```

thanks for your help